# Why my React App does not fire up in browser automatically?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I am learning React now. I create the app by using

```
npx create-react-app .
npm start
```

Then I get:

```
Compiled successfully!

You can now view recipe_app in the browser.

  Local:            http://localhost:3000
  On Your Network:  http://192.168.0.11:3000

Note that the development build is not optimized.
To create a production build, use npm run build.
```

The compilation works fine, but the application does not open in my browser (I use firefox.) automatically, so I have to manually open it by typing the URL in my browser. I thought React should fire up the app by default? I am not sure what is wrong. I tried the following solutions but none of them work.

1. Use `BROWSER=firefox npm start` in my terminal.
2. Set `BROWSER` variable in `package.json`:

```
// package.json
"scripts": {
    "start": "BROWSER='firefox' react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

3. or add `cross-env` in the `scripts`

```
// package.json
"scripts": {
    "start": "cross-env BROWSER='firefox' react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

None of these solutions work. The application can be compiled successfully but it just does not open up in my browser. Here is my full `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "recipe_app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.12.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.6",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "BROWSER=firefox react-scripts start",
    "chrome": "BROWSER='google-chrome' react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

I am using `vscode 1.55.2`, `firefox 88.0`, `npm 6.14.11`, `node v14.15.1`, and `Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS`. Can anyone help me? Thank you!

Comment: If you try to open firefox (or chrome) from a terminal, does it work? I.e. are your browsers in your PATH?

Comment: @Gregoire Lodi. You are right! The browsers are not in my PATH. I never thought about this because I knew firefox was in my PATH, but somehow it is not in the PATH of the integrated terminal of vscode... I run `npm start` in my system terminal and there is no problem. Not sure why it does not work in vscode integrated terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. It is because `$DISPLAY` is not in the environment variables of the vscode's integrated terminal.

In order to fire up `firefox`, I need to set `export DISPLAY=:0`. But this is a one-time fix.

I do have `$DISPLAY` in my `zsh` terminal, clearly, vscode does not inherit it. So I need to set the `inheritEnv` to be `true` in the `setting.json` file.

Open `~/.config/Code/User/settings.json`, and set:

```
"terminal.integrated.inheritEnv": true
```

Then re-start vscode. To ensure your modification works, just type in your terminal:

```
echo $DISPLAY
:0 // you get this
```

You are good to go.